# AngularDart: Creating a Form with Reactive Form Builder

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I'm trying to create from using `AngularDart 5`, `angular_forms 2`. The API seems to be very different from `angular_forms 1` and I cannot figure out how to create a `FormGroup` using `FormBuilder` and `ControlGroup`. Below is my code.

*LoginComponent.dart*

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_forms/angular_forms.dart';

@Component(
    selector: 'login-comp',
    templateUrl: 'login_component.html',
    styleUrls: ['login_component.css'],
    directives: [formDirectives, coreDirectives])
class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  ControlGroup ctrlGrp;

  LoginComponent() {
    this._createForm();
  }

  void _createForm() {
    final email = Control<String>('', Validators.required);
    final password = Control<String>(
        '', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]));

    this.ctrlGrp =
        FormBuilder.controlGroup({'email': email, 'password': password});
  }

  @override
  void ngOnInit() {}

  void submit() {}
}
```

*login_component.html*

```
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center align-times-center">
    <div class="form-wrapper text-center">
        <h2 class="text-center">Login</h2>
        <form novalidate #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
            <div ngControlGroup="ctrlGrp">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" ngControl="email" class="form-control" id="email-input"
                           placeholder="Enter Email" formControlName="email"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" ngControl="password" class="form-control" id="password-input"
                           placeholder="Enter Password" formControlName="password"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!f.valid">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <small><a [routerLink]="'/signup'">Need an Account?</a></small>
    </div>
</div>
```

*pubspec.yaml*

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.0.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  angular: ^5.0.0
  ng_bootstrap: ^1.1.1
  sass_builder: ^2.0.0
  angular_router: ^2.0.0-alpha+19
  angular_forms: ^2.1.1

dev_dependencies:
  angular_test: ^2.0.0
  build_runner: ^1.0.0
  build_test: ^0.10.2
  build_web_compilers: ^0.4.0
  test: ^1.0.0
```

- How can I create a `FormGroup` with `angular_forms 2`?
- How can I bind a from group to `formGroup` attribute in html template?

Thanks.

Comment: why is this question downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add ngFormModel in you form tag:

```
<form novalidate #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()" [ngFormModel]="ctrlGrp"></form>
```

Comment: `#f="ngForm" ` wasn't need for my case.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to find the answer with the help of @ebelair.

I was missing the `[ngFormModel]="loginForm"` part.
Below is the working code.

*login_component.dart*

```
@Component(
    selector: 'login-comp',
    templateUrl: 'login_component.html',
    styleUrls: ['login_component.css'],
    directives: [formDirectives, coreDirectives, routerDirectives])
class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  ControlGroup loginForm;

  LoginComponent() {
    this._createForm();
  }

  void _createForm() {
    final email = Control<String>('', Validators.required);
    final password = Control<String>('', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]));

    this.loginForm = FormBuilder.controlGroup({'email': email, 'password': password});
  }

  @override
  void ngOnInit() {}

  void submit() {
    print(this.loginForm.value['email']);
    print(this.loginForm.value['password']);
  }
}
```

*login_component.html*

```
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center align-times-center">
    <div class="form-wrapper text-center">
        <h2 class="text-center">Login</h2>
        <form novalidate [ngFormModel]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
            <div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" ngControl="email" class="form-control" id="email-input"
                           placeholder="Enter Email" formControlName="email"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" ngControl="password" class="form-control" id="password-input"
                           placeholder="Enter Password" formControlName="password"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <small><a [routerLink]="'/signup'">Need an Account?</a></small>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does this still trigger the validation after an onblur event of the element like if you had placed required on the input itself?  Also, can you use this with the angulardart material components, like <material-input>